# Get an XML response with a java http post request on GeoNetwork

Tags: java, http, post, jetty, geonetwork

I try to complete automatically my GeoNetwork catalog with java http post request. No matter the library (io, apache commons, geotools), I always have the same html response as follow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  SYSTEM "html">
<html ng-app="gn_login" lang="eng" id="ng-app">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>My GeoNetwork catalogue - My organization</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 48x48" type="image/png" href="../../i$
      <link href="rss.search?sortBy=changeDate" rel="alternate" type="applicati$
      <link href="portal.opensearch" rel="search" type="application/opensearchd$
      <link href="/geonetwork/static/gn_login_default.css" rel="stylesheet" med$
      <link href="/geonetwork/static/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" $
      <link href="/geonetwork/static/ng-skos.css" rel="stylesheet" media="scree$
      <link href="/geonetwork/static/srv_custom_style.css" rel="stylesheet" med$
   </head>
   <body data-ng-controller="GnCatController">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default gn-top-bar" data-ng-hide="layout.hideTo$
      <div data-ng-include="'../../catalog/templates/signin.html'"></div>
      <div ng-include="'../../catalog/templates/info.html'"></div><script src="$
         <div class="alert" data-ng-hide=""><strong></strong>
         </div>
      </noscript>
   </body>
</html>
```

I start my GeoNetwork with jetty server. Do you know how to directly request the server to get an XML response?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to make the request to a protected URL. You must make a request to the login service first, keep the `JSESSIONID` cookie it returns and then send it to the original service you wanted to request.